# Yearly onshore wind turbine energy production

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, electricity, kinetic-theory, solar-wind

I am trying to work out the yearly energy production of an onshore Siemens SWT-3.0-101, hub height 94m, total height 144,5. Here is the power curve at each wind speed level worked out through a software:

[image: power curve]

I am trying to work out the average yearly production at wind speed= 8 m/s.

My calculations are the following: 1138(=Kw at 8 m/s wind speed)*3600(=sec in 1hr)=4096800 KW/h; 4096800Kw/h*6765,81(hours in one year)=27718170408Kw/h in one year=27718,17GW/h in one year. This is my result, but everywhere is said that an yearly yeld of an onshore wind turbine stays around 5.5-6 GW/h, which is very far from my result.

Where am I wrong? Thank you very much in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You're almost right.

But... 1138 kilowatts power output will give you 1138 kilowatt-hours in, well... one hour, not 1 second.  Just leave out the $\times 3600$

It's better to avoid weird units(like kilowatt-hours as much as possible, so another longer way is this:

$1138 \text{ kilowatts}$ mean $1,138,000\text{ joules/sec}$

So in one year you'll get $1,138,000\times 3600\times 24 \times 365=3.5888\times 10^{13}\text{ joules}=A$

$ 1\text{ kilowatt-hour}$ means $1000 \times 3600=3.6 \times 10^6\text{ joules}=B$

Divide the $A$ by $B$ and you're done.

I had a professor who had us use furlongs/fortnight$^2$ as a unit of acceleration, and had us express distances in knot-seconds.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your measurement unit is wrong. Energy is measured in, say, kWh, not kW/h. Second, you should not multiply by 3600, as the final result is in kilowatt-hours.